# writing cleaner tidier PostgreSQL/PostGIS query

Tags: postgresql, postgis

This query creates a municipal summary report of all the receptors counts that fall within the road buffer zone and it is grouped by municipalities.

SO essentially the output would be

```
munname    school   childcare  hospitals etc...
"mun1"         3         4        0 
"mun2"         1         0         9


select b.mun,b.county,q1.schools,q2.childcares,q3.hospitals,q4.nursinghomes,q5.infrastructure,q6.streamwmi,q7.streammi,q8.rez,b.geometry into roadreport
        from (select muntruck.munname as mun,muntruck.muncounty as county,mun.geom as geometry from muntruck,mun 
            where muntruck.munname = mun.mun and muntruck.muncounty = mun.county) as b 
            left join(select count(schools.gid) as schools,muntruck.munname as mun,muntruck.muncounty as county from muntruck,schools
                where st_intersects(muntruck.igeom,schools.geom) group by muntruck.muncounty,muntruck.munname) as q1
                    on b.mun = q1.mun and b.county = q1.county 
            left join(select count(childcare.gid) as childcares,muntruck.munname as mun,muntruck.muncounty as county from muntruck,childcare 
                where st_intersects(muntruck.igeom,childcare.geom) group by muntruck.muncounty,muntruck.munname) as q2 
                    on b.mun = q2.mun and b.county = q2.county 
            left join(select count(hospitals.gid) as hospitals, muntruck.munname as mun,muntruck.muncounty as county from muntruck,hospitals
                where st_intersects(muntruck.igeom,hospitals.geom) group by muntruck.muncounty,muntruck.munname) as q3 
                    on b.mun = q3.mun and b.county = q3.county
            left join(select count(nursinghomes.gid) as nursinghomes, muntruck.munname as mun,muntruck.muncounty as county from muntruck,nursinghomes
                where st_intersects(muntruck.igeom,nursinghomes.geom) group by muntruck.muncounty,muntruck.munname) as q4
                    on b.mun = q4.mun and b.county = q4.county
            left join(select count(infra.gid) as infrastructure,muntruck.munname as mun,muntruck.muncounty as county from muntruck,infra
                where st_intersects(muntruck.igeom,infra.ggeom) group by muntruck.muncounty,muntruck.munname) as q5
                    on b.mun = q5.mun and b.county = q5.county
            left join(select sum(st_length(geom))/5280 as streamwmi, muntruck.munname as mun,muntruck.muncounty as county from muntruck, streamsw
                where st_intersects(muntruck.igeom,streamsw.geom) group by muntruck.muncounty,muntruck.munname) as q6
                    on b.mun = q6.mun and b.county = q6.county
            left join(select sum(st_length(geom))/5280 as streammi, muntruck.munname as mun,muntruck.muncounty as county from muntruck,streams
                where st_intersects(muntruck.igeom,streams.geom) group by muntruck.muncounty,muntruck.munname) as q7
                    on b.mun = q7.mun and b.county = q7.county
            left join(select sum(popest*((ST_Area(residentialpopulation.geom)/43560)/acresnew)) as rez, muntruck.munname as mun,muntruck.muncounty as county from muntruck,residentialpopulation
                where st_intersects(muntruck.igeom,residentialpopulation.geom) group by muntruck.muncounty,muntruck.munname) as q8
                    on b.mun = q8.mun and b.county = q8.county;
```

it runs totally fine and creates a file with the correct counts for each municipality. I was just wondering if there is superfluous code in here? can it be cleaner, less messy? any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is this query the output of an ORM? (when not: seek help)

Comment: i am not sure what ORM is? it is a GIS shapefile..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your query, in every subquery you count records for municipalities joined with some other table (schools, hospitals, etc). I think you could do all the joins at once, like:

```
SELECT 
    muntruck.munname AS mun,
    muntruck.muncounty AS county,
    mun.geom as geometry,
    COUNT(schools.gid) AS schools,
    COUNT(childcare.gid) AS childcares,
    COUNT(hospitals.gid) AS hospitals
FROM muntruck
JOIN mun ON (muntruck.munname = mun.mun AND muntruck.muncounty = mun.county)
LEFT JOIN schools ON ST_Intersects(muntruck.igeom, schools.geom)
LEFT JOIN childcare ON ST_Intersects(muntruck.igeom, childcare.geom)
LEFT JOIN hospitals ON ST_Intersects(muntruck.igeom, hospitals.geom)
GROUP BY 
    muntruck.muncounty,
    muntruck.munname,
    mun.geom
```

It looks much cleaner and understandable and I think it produces the same result.

Comment: FYI you put extra parenthesis on the st_intersects after the left joins but your structure worked

Comment: @ziggy, thanks for spotting this, fixed parenthisis.

Comment: For some reason tho, my original query took about 20 min to run and yours took about 2+ hours. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: To be honest, not without `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Could you publish it? Probably it's better to do as a separate question.